# Is it allowed to use LIKE for NUMBER datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

There is a procedure which tries to fetch details of project/s from PROJECTS table.
The snippet goes here:

```
PROCEDURE GET_PROJECTS (
        P_PROJECT_ID_LIKE    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '%',
        P_SEPARATOR          IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '-=-' )
      AS
        CURSOR PROJECTS_CURSOR IS
          .....

      WHERE
         PROJECT_ID LIKE P_PROJECT_ID_LIKE
```

The concern is:

```
PROJECT_ID         has a datatype - NUMBER.  
P_PROJECT_ID_LIKE  has a datatype - VARCHAR2.
```

I am wondering how LIKE can be used on PROJECT_ID ?

It is working perfectly fine for

```
GET_PROJECTS('%','-=-');  
GET_PROJECTS('28','-=-')
```

Any insight would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit type conversion will take place. Notice `1 - filter(TO_CHAR("N") LIKE 'asdf%')` in predicate information section.

```
15:13:51 (133)LKU@sandbox> create table t (n number);                     

Table created.                                                            

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10                                                      
15:14:22 (133)LKU@sandbox> select * from t where n like 'asdf%'           
15:14:37   2                                                              
15:14:37 (133)LKU@sandbox> @xplan                                         

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873                                               

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):             
-------------------------------------------------------------             

   1 - SEL$1 / T@SEL$1                                                    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                       
---------------------------------------------------                       

   1 - filter(TO_CHAR("N") LIKE 'asdf%')                                  

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):               
-----------------------------------------------------------               

   1 - "N"[NUMBER,22]
```

In either case, it doesn't make much sense to filter identifiers using `like` operator. If you want to get all values in case certain condition is met, then you should probably do it sort of this way:

```
where project_id = P_PROJECT_ID or P_PROJECT_ID = -1
```

using basically any numeric value that is not a valid project id.

Answer (score 0):

As @be here now suggested an implicit conversion will take place. This will work 99% of the times but there are some cavets when reaching big numbers.

Take this scenario for example,

```
SQL> select to_char(power(2,140)) from dual;

TO_CHAR(POWER(2,140))
----------------------------------------
1.3937965749081639463459823920405226E+42
```

The number was converted to char with an exponential notation. So some string might not match.

If you don't reach these numbers you should be fine.

Although this is an oracle question take some advice from the [Zen Of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score -3):

I didn't check this in Oracle but In SQL Server it is possible to use like against an INT attribute,

for example

```
Create table mytable(
id int not null ,
name varchar(50))
```

then you can select with like

```
select * from mytable where id like '123%'
```

And the reason why this is possible is that char is an Integral type.

`so in my conclusion ,this might be possible in oracle too please check.`

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. `char` isn't an integral type in the first place, but if it were, your reasoning would mean that other (non-integer) types cannot be checked with `LIKE`. You can easily verify that it also works with (for example) `timestamp`.